# Visual Studio stops responding

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

How about this time I come with a detail a little outside of code programming, but what happens is that I work on a project in .net with Aspx and Dev Express in which I am editing the design of some forms but at the time of wanting to add some text box or button component in the html when wanting to synchronize the view with the code, visual studio stops responding for around 3 minutes until it generates the new change in the design and this happens with the slightest change that occurs account .
This takes up a lot of my time and generates despair. I hope you can help me.
Greetings.

Comment: In most cases, this suggest your virus scanning software is messing things up.  Also, you can try tapping windows key, type in visual studio 2019, and then right click and run as administrator - often that fixes this issue due to the folder having some elevated rights.

Comment: In addition to Albert D. Kallal's suggestion, I also recommend that you check whether you have any extensions related to Dev Express installed. If you are dragging Dev Express controls that cause Visual Studio to stop responding, you can try updating or reinstalling these extensions.

Comment: What's up, do the options that were suggested to me and it continues in the same way, it does not respond and consumes a lot of memory, the equipment that I personally use for me is a good ThinkPad range with Intel Core i7 Processor, 16 GB Ram, Hard Drive in solid state 1 TB, I don't know why Visual Studio behaves like this. GREETINGS

Comment: If you confirm that the expansion of the three parties caused this issue, you can try to use Visual Studio Installer to repair Visual Studio

Comment: I have already installed 2 versions of visual, Community and Entreprise and I don't see any improvement. Now I completely don't know the reason why he reacts like this.